Wrong field types when connecting to MSSQL DB with user-defined data types using PyQGIS
When I connect to an MSSQL table without geometry via QgsDataSourceUri, Browser or Data Source Manager, QGIS doesn't recognize the user-defined data types of the database and sets it to string.

from qgis.core import QgsDataSourceUri, QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject

uri = QgsDataSourceUri()

host = "DBSERVER"
database = "mydb"
table = "TMP"

uri.setConnection(host, '', database, '', '')
uri.setDataSource(None, f'{table}', None, None, aKeyColumn='TMP_ID')
tableLayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "test", "mssql")

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(tableLayer)

Is there a way to adjust the types?

A bit primitive approach without considering the db, you can try setting up field types via extending the uri treated by the QgsVectorDataProvider by specifying the &field=name:type(length, precision), see the parameters of the memory QgsVectorLayer: https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#providers

I already tried that. But I have to create a QgsVectorLayer and then assign the dataProvider to it. But when I create the QgsVectorLayer it allready needs the URL eg. QgsDataSourceUri, memory, etc. When I use the QgsDataSourceUri, the fields are already loaded before being able to set them with the dataProvider.
